# Angular HttpClient get, wrong this object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, httpclient

in my Angular App i make a simple call to a node.js server. the HttpClient "get"
function returns the right answer. This answer I want to store in a variable of my component "interfaces". But in the "subscribe" function of the get request my "this" pointer doesn't point to my component. Instead it tells me that it is of type "SafeSubscriber". Any call to my member "interfaces" lead to the following error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'interfaces' of undefined**

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

public interfaces : string[];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.interfaces = [];
    this.interfaces.push("huhu");

}

ngOnInit() : void {

    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/settings/interfaces').subscribe((data) => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        console.log(data);
        this.interfaces.push("xxx");
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
            console.log(k);
            this.interfaces.push("xxx");
        });
    }),
    err => {
      console.log("error " + err);
    }; 
}
```

}

As you can see I also tried to enter some values manually into the array just to make sure, that not the server response is causing the problem.
Any help is appreciated.

I used this code as a blueprint which is from:
https://angular.io/guide/http

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` can be relative. If you want to test and be sure, store `this` as a variable.

example using jQuery

`$('body').on('click','.previewButton',function() {
  var thisEL = $(this);
});`

This allows you to reference to correct instance of `this` when necessary.

Comment: yes but I though (or my understanding was), that the call of get(...).subscribe is a kind of closure were I can access my "this" point of the component. Or am I totally wrong??

Comment: Im not sure about the particular instance, Im more familiar however with the general potential issues of `this` as a reference. In some cases these issues are universal. You can test by throwing it into a variable and dumping vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing reference to the correct `this` in this statement:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {..})
```

Inside the function block code `this` refers to the calling context , which is the subscribe method itself, that's why `interfaces` is undefined, since it's not a property of the subscribe method.

You can change the function for a lambda en it should be fine:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => {..})
```

Comment: Good spot. However, *which is the subscribe method itself* is not the case inside of the `forEach`. `this` will be `undefined` (the error message even says so).

Comment: Thx a lot. That was it. changed to 'lambda' and it works as expected.